# What is the difference between !($x == ' ' OR $y == ' ') and $x != ' ' OR $y != ' '

Tags: php, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, explain

What is the difference of between the following examples?

**FIRST EXAMPLE**

```
if($x != '' or $y != '' or $z!=''or $c!=''){
    echo "<h3>YOUR INPUT:</h3>";
    echo $x.'<br>'.$y.'<br>'.$z.'<br>'.$c.'<br>';
}
```

**SECOND EXAMPLE**

```
if(!($x == '' or $y == '' or $z==''or $c=='')){
    echo "<h3>YOUR INPUT:</h3>";
    echo $x.'<br>'.$y.'<br>'.$z.'<br>'.$c.'<br>';
}
```

Please explain. I'm newbie in programming. I couldn't get it when someone post it in my question and I saw the code I thought it was the same as the title, but I tried it and I saw the difference. Help me to understand this.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Make a list of possible inputs and whether each of the two conditions are fulfilled. You will find that they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

`$x != '' or $y != '' or $z!=''or $c!=''` is `true` if **any** of the variables are not empty. If any of the variables are `abc` or are otherwise not `''`, the condition is `true`.

`!($x == '' or $y == '' or $z==''or $c=='')` is `true` only if **all** of the variables are not empty. Another more readable expression of those conditions is:

```
$x != '' and $y != '' and $z != '' and $c != ''
```

Comment: y did he use or instead of and in the second

Comment: The last 2 statements mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

use this code is better you know what is it mean x,y,z & c is not empty give result. || is mean or.

```
if(!empty($x) || !empty($y) || !empty($z) || !empty($c)){
    echo "<h3>YOUR INPUT:</h3>";
    echo $x.'<br>'.$y.'<br>'.$z.'<br>'.$c.'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example would work if any of the four variables is not empty.
The second example would work only when none of the four variables is empty.